# MYSQL order by another tables column but needs some (and) conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Here are the database tables and some records
[image]

What I want to achieve is to
select everything from products sort conditions (ORDER BY) are
first, products_campaign end_date ASC.
Second, products score DESC
BUT the WHERE conditions are products_campaign enable equals to 1

So as the result. I want to display all products as sort with first it has active campaign(enable) sort by end_date if not then sort by score.
Mention: some products do not have records in products_campaign (e.g.productID:104).
I tried use LEFT JOIN but the productID 104 wouldn't be selected into result list.

Any help?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM PRODUCTS A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS_CAMPAIGN WHERE ENABLE = 1) AS B
ON A.PRODUCT_ID = B.PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY B.END_DATE ASC, A.SCORE DESC
```

Comment: No, I tried LEFT OUTER JOIN but it does not work. Like the productID 102 wouldn't be selected. Because the enable is 0. I want select all products as the primary requirement.

Comment: then what is your where condition ENABLE = 1. have edited my answer. Check if that is what you expect

Comment: only enable = 1's productID in product_campaign will be order by end_date ASC. if not found in product_campaign (no records or enable = 0) will be order by product table product.score DESC

Comment: add your expected output to your question